# Born Rule proof for freshmen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, probability, born-rule

Although early quantum mechanics are taught in many freshman courses, the Born Rule is almost never proved at that stage. Is it even impossible to elementarily prove that the probability density is not attained by the third or fourth (or any number different from two) power of the wavefunction?

Comment: Fundamental assumptions in physics are not provable, any more than axioms in mathematics are provable. The Born rule is simply a *postulate* that *works*.

Comment: I think people have proposed various less-common fundamental assumptions for quantum mechanics from which the Born rule *can* be derived, but then *those* assumptions are postulates, which doesn’t really change the situation. Which postulates you prefer is just a matter of taste, because they lead to the same *predictions* when you do a calculation.

Comment: @G.Smith Thank you for enlightening me. I should have written 'confirming' Born Rules. If you could also answer my question, I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: The Born Rule is confirmed by experiment. I don’t understand what your question is. $|\psi|^2$ works, while $|\psi|^4$ etc. doesn’t work. There isn’t more to say.

Comment: [This](https://www.scottaaronson.com/democritus/lec9.html) is an accessible yet technical discussion of some of the motivations people have offered for, among other things, the Born rule.

Comment: @G.Smith Would you please elucidate why $\psi^4$ doesn't work?

Comment: Born's rule cannot be derived (this is part of the so-called measurement problem), but it can be motivated by showing that alternatives would have undesirable properties. That's what [Gleason's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gleason%27s_theorem) does. It doesn't count as a derivation of Born's rule, because it doesn't know which observables have been measured. (That matters because applying Born's rule to unmeasured observables would give nonsense.) But it does count as a self-consistency argument that rules out alternatives to Born's rule, given a few seemingly natural assumptions.